# ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName can I shift function next positional parameters?

Tags: powershell, pipeline, powershell-cmdlet

Considering to functions designed to use values by property name, the second function have his first argument passed by pipeline. Can I use positional parameter for this second function?

Example:

```bsh
function Get-Customer {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [string]$CustomerName = "*"
    )
    Process {
        # real process iterate on fodlers.
        New-Object PSObject -Property @{
            CustomerName = $CustomerName;
        }
    }
}

function Get-Device {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName)]
        [string]$CustomerName = "*",
        [string]$DeviceName = "*"
    )

    Process {
        # real process iterate on fodlers.
        New-Object PSObject -Property @{
            CustomerName=$CustomerName;
            DeviceName=$DeviceName
        }
    }
}
```

You can use it like:

```
Get-Customer "John" | Get-Device
Get-Customer "John" | Get-Device -DeviceName "Device 1"
```

But can you do this (actually with provided code it doesn't work)?

```
Get-Customer "John" | Get-Device "Device 1"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define `$DeviceName` as the first positional parameter for that to work:

```
function Get-Device {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName)]
        [string]$CustomerName = "*",

        [Parameter(Position=0)]
        [string]$DeviceName = "*"
    )

    Process {
        # real process iterate on fodlers.
        New-Object PSObject -Property @{
            CustomerName = $CustomerName;
            DeviceName   = $DeviceName
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to get this syntax? :
`Get-Customer "John" | Get-Device "Device 1" `   

And also    

`Get-Device "John" "Device 1"`

Comment: @Manea No. You can't have positional parameters with varying positions unless you have distinguishable parameter sets. Which you don't